# How do I fix the group by statement

Tags: sql

here is the question

Using Sales.SalesTerritory and Sales.SalesOrderHeader, find out the territories that have more than 1000 sales orders. Please return the TerritoryID, the Territory Name, and the total number of sales orders. Order by the total number of sales orders.

here is my code

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nGn1Z.png)

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated thank you.

Comment: Show us query and error message as test, not as a link to an image. And add a tag for the dbms you're using.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a server to try that out, but you might want to try the following: Move the WHERE part below the GROUP BY part and change WHERE to HAVING

```
SELECT 
    SalesOrderHeader.TerritoryID, Name, SUM(COUNT(SalesOrderNumber)) AS 'Total Sales Orders' 
FROM 
    Sales.SalesTerritory
INNER JOIN ...
GROUP BY 
    SalesOrderHeader.TerritoryID
HAVING 
    SUM(COUNT(SalesOrderNumber)) > 1000;
```

I am not sure if you can use the alias, but maybe even that is possible.